# How to spy an EJB with mockito?

Tags: java, ejb, mockito

If for normal classes it's `@Spy ClassToBeSpied class = new ClassToBeSpied();`
What about an EJB? Is it possible doing that without having to use an embedded web server?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can spy EJB classes, but this way you won't have any standard EJB features, like transactions. It will behave like "normal" Java object, as it is created outside EJB context.